# Creating a new list based on the conditions of the dictionary nested in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, append

I am new to Python. I am trying to create a new list based on a specific condition, which is `fruits['type'] === 'edit'`.

```py
fruits = [{'type': 'edit',
  'ns': 0,
  'title': 'List',
  'pageid': 39338740},
 {'type': 'new',
  'ns': 0,
  'title': 'John Braid',
  'pageid': 8164456},
 {'type': 'edit',
  'ns': 0,
  'title': 'lokan',
  'pageid': 65869267}]
```

My code returns an empty array:

```py
newlist = []

for x in fruits:
  if x['type'] == 'edit' in x:
    newlist.append(x)

print(newlist)
```

Comment: simply `if x['type'] == 'edit':`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fruits = [{'type': 'edit',
  'ns': 0,
  'title': 'List',
  'pageid': 39338740},
 {'type': 'new',
  'ns': 0,
  'title': 'John Braid',
  'pageid': 8164456},
 {'type': 'edit',
  'ns': 0,
  'title': 'lokan',
  'pageid': 65869267}]

newlist = [fruit for fruit in fruits if fruit["type"] == "edit"]

print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create new list with list comprehension,

```
new_list = [d for d in fruits if d['type'] == 'edit']
```

Which is equal to,

```
new_list = [] 
for d in fruits:
    if d['type'] == 'edit':
         new_list.append(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in fruits:
    try:
        if x['type'] == 'edit':
            newlist.append(x)
    except:
        pass

print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't work, as you included `in x` in your `if` statement, which was already answered. But I wanted to include further explanation, which hopefully will be helpful.

`x['type'] == 'edit'` evaluates to `True` or `False` which means that your code:

```py
if x['type'] == 'edit' in x
```

actually looks like that when you intended it to append to the list:

```py
if True in x
```

And `True` is, of course, not an element of `x`, so this is `False`, so your list never is appended.